# How to know if cell exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

I searched but could not find the way to do this.

I want to know if this is possible

```
if ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2) present
  do some stuff
end if
```

Comment: If it wasn't present wouldn't that throw an error ?

Comment: I am new and not able to understand handling it by error. Yes it indeed gives error.

Comment: Yep, and you can test for that.

Comment: @vacip: Please see community wiki answer I posted. I will delete after checking if Ok. Please edit if needed and then I will delete the answer to accept yours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can work:

```
Dim mycell as cell

On Error Resume Next 'If an error happens after this point, just move on like nothing happened
  Set mycell = ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1) 'try grabbing a cell in the table
On Error GoTo 0 'If an error happens after this point, do the normal Error message thingy
If mycell Is Nothing Then 'check if we have managed to grab anything
  MsgBox "no cell"
Else
  MsgBox "got cell"
End If
```

If you want to test for multiple cells in a loop, don't forget to `set mycell=nothing` before trying again.

(Instead of the mycell variable way, you could also check to see if an error has happened when you tried to use the cell. You could use `If err > 0 Then` to do that. But that way is a bit more unstable in my experience.)

---

Specific answer to OP's specific question:

```
If .Find.Found Then 'this is custom text search, has nothing to do with specified cell exist.
 Set testcell = Nothing
 On Error Resume Next
   Set testcell = tbl.Cell(i, 6)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If Not testcell Is Nothing Then
   tbl.Cell(i, 2).Merge MergeTo:=tbl.Cell(i, 3)
 End If
End If
```

This means:

```
If your .find does whatever... then
  Try grabbing the cell in question (the 4 rows: Set...Nothing, On error..., Set..., On Error...)
  If we could grab the cell, then merge cells
```

Read up a bit on the error handling in VBA, the On Error statement. In VBA, there is no Try...Catch. This is what we can do instead.

I hope this clears it up.

---

For reference, I'll post a full code here:

```
Sub test()

Dim tbl As Table
Dim testcell As Cell

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Range.Tables(1)

For i = 1 To 6

  Set testcell = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
    Set testcell = tbl.Cell(i, 6)
  On Error GoTo 0

  If Not testcell Is Nothing Then
    tbl.Cell(i, 2).Merge MergeTo:=tbl.Cell(i, 3)
  End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It will take a while for me to understand. I will comment then.

Comment: `IsEmpty` checks the value in that cell not the presence of cell itself so I am not sure how that'll help detect if a cell is there in a table.

Comment: Basically I try to set a variable to the cell. This means, I try to use the cell. If I fail, that means there is no such cell in the table, so my variable will be empty. If I succeed, I will have something in my variable.

Comment: @newguy No, `IsEmpty` checks if there is anything in the **variable**. If there is nothing in the variable, that means there is no cell. mycell is an object variable. It is a pointer. Let me update my code.

Comment: See the update. `mycell` is an object variable of the type `Cell`. It is a pointer. We try to set it to the cell in question. If there is no cell, it points to nothing. If there is a cell, it points to something (that cell). All we need to do is check whether it points to `nothing` or not.

Comment: @vacip I would if this was my question :)

Comment: Yup. Did The job ✓. Please see my(your modified) answer if I am doing it the way you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution as a function for reference...

```
Function cellExists(t As table, i As Integer, j As Integer) As Boolean
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim c As cell
  Set c = t.cell(i, j)
  On Error GoTo 0
  cellExists = Not c Is Nothing
End Function
```